# How to change menu on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, authentication, menu

I am trying to make an authentication based menus in react app.

**Menu Data:**

```
const menuItems = {
    primaryMenus: [
      { title: 'Messages' },
      { title: 'Register' },
      {
        subMenus: { 
          title: 'Account',
          menus: [{ title: "Profile" }, { title: "Change Password"}],
        },
      },
      { title: 'Help' }
    ],
  };
```

From the above data, I need to build up the menu structure.

**The code that I have tried so far**

```js
  const menuItems = {
    primaryMenus: [
      { title: 'Messages' },
      { title: 'Register' },
      {
        subMenus: { 
          title: 'Account',
          menus: [{ title: "Profile" }, { title: "Change Password"}],
        },
      },
      { title: 'Help' }
    ],
  };


function App() {

  const [ isAuthenticated, setAuthenticated ] = React.useState(false);
  
  return(
  <div>
   <button onClick={() => {setAuthenticated(!isAuthenticated)}}>            {isAuthenticated ? 'Logout' : 'Login'} </button>

   <ul className="menu">
    {menuItems.primaryMenus.map((menu, i) => { 
        return (
        !menu.subMenus ?
          <li key={i}> {menu.title} </li>
          :
          <li key={i}>
            {menu.subMenus.title}
           <ul>
           { menu.subMenus.menus.map((submenu, j) => {
             return <li key={j}> {submenu.title} </li>
           }) }
           </ul>
          </li>
        )
    })}
   </ul>
   
    <h1> The menu Messages and Help will be there for both logged in user and logged out user </h1>
   <br />
   <h1> Whereas the Register menu will be available only if user is logged out </h1>
   <br />
      <h1> My Account menu and its submenus will be available only if user is logged in </h1>
   </div>
  )

}





ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

**Requirement:**

Menu structure for **logged in** user:

```
- Messages
- Account
   - Profile
   - Change Password
- Help
```

Menu structure for **logged out** user:

```
- Messages
- Register
- Help
```

I can modify the provided json structure `(menuItems)` as well..

Kindly help me to achieve the above result.

I am new to react, so if anyone could provide me a solution in pure react way of authentication then it would be much more helpful for me..

Comment: By the looks of your code, you can check if authenticated and submenu `!menu.subMenus && !isAuthenticated`.

Comment: I hope this isn't the direction for authentication in your app. I would use redux to store the user authentication state instead of using component state.

Comment: @designtocode, Thanks for your comment.. Could you kindly provide me solution how to handle it in pure react way as I am totally new to it?  Thanks in advance..

Comment: Well as a suggestion, if your app grows bigger, it's ideal to have a global state/store with the user data. You can find out more about redux here https://redux.js.org/ Alternatively you can follow this guide which has user authentication at parent App component state https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-login-authentication-to-react-applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you changed the structure of the array `menuItems`. For example like this:

```
  const menuItems = [
    { title: 'Messages', whenLoggedIn: true, whenLoggedOut: true },
    { title: 'Help', whenLoggedIn: true, whenLoggedOut: true },
    { title: 'Register', whenLoggedIn: false, whenLoggedOut: true },
    {
      title: 'Account',
      whenLoggedIn: true,
      whenLoggedOut: false,
      subMenuItems: [{ title: 'Profile' }, { title: 'Change password' }],
    },
  ];
```

Then you can use them like this:

```
      const keepMenuItem = (menuItem, isAuthenticated) => 
        (isAuthenticated && menuItem.whenLoggedIn) 
        || (!isAuthenticated && menuItem.whenLoggedOut)


    return (
        <ul className="menu">
          {menuItems.filter(menuItem => keepMenuItem(menuItem, isAuthenticated)
                    .map(menuItem => (
            <li key={menuItem.title}>
              {menuItem.title}
              {!!menuItem.subMenuItems && (
                <ul>
                  {menuItem.subMenuItems.map(subMenuItem => (
                    <li key={subMenuItem.title}>{subMenuItem.title}</li>
                  ))}{' '}
                </ul>
              )}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
```